# C# ListBox deleting item

Tags: c#, listbox

Hello I've read countless threads on removing `ListBox` items and I have tried many different methods but I still keep getting this bug.

When I try to remove an item and there is another item in the ListBox with the exact same name, it removes the other item.
[Here is a GIF](https://gyazo.com/f1c9ca1e1d501dae9fc3965e5092cacf) explaining it.

the code I use to remove item from ListBox is below:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null) {
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    utils.updateScript(script, listBox1);

    listBox1.SelectedItem = null;
}
else {
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a script command to delete");
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. interesting... Is there a RemoveAt method? Maybe that helps. You can then delete by index.

Comment: What are your ListBox items? If they are strings, then it's removing the first one because they're equal. Please show us how you populate the ListBox.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be working. listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

this appears to be working!

Comment: NIce! Don't forget to mark your question as "answer" later ;-)